# Behavior of Float overflow in C

Tags: c

I am new to C, up until now I've only used OOP languages and never had to focus much on memory or how bits work, and I need help wrapping my head around what's happening here.

I have to test the minimum and maximum bounds of each data type in C by initializing a variable to the min/max value of the data type and attempting to add or subtract 1.  I've gotten past the integer types and now I am confused on the behavior of the Float type.  A lot of what I've been reading is a little over my head, I would really appreciate if someone could help me understand how these types work.

This is what I have for testing a Float:

```
void DisplayFloatMinimumAndMaximum()
{
// Declare variables
float fltMinimum = 0;
float fltMaximum = 0;

// Set min/max values
fltMinimum = -3.4e38;
fltMaximum = 3.4e38;

printf("Float Minimum and Maximum\n");
printf("------------------------------------------------\n");
printf("Float Minimum : %.10e\n", fltMinimum);
printf("Float Maximum : %.10e\n", fltMaximum);
printf("\n");

fltMinimum -= 1.0f;
fltMaximum += 1.0f;

printf("Confirmation\n");
printf("Float Minimum : %.10e\n", fltMinimum);
printf("Float Maximum : %.10e\n", fltMaximum);
printf("\n");
}
```

and I am getting a result of:

```
Float Minimum and Maximum
------------------------------------------------
Float Minimum : -3.3999999521e+38
Float Maximum : 3.3999999521e+38

Confirmation
Float Minimum : -3.3999999521e+38
Float Maximum : 3.3999999521e+38
```

It appears as nothing happened at all.
Is this the correct behavior?  If so, why?  If not, why?

(I am using Visual Studio 2015)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Due to the floating point nature of the data, adding/subbing 1 to such a big number does nothing because the value is "absorbed" (as Weather commented, before adding the two operands, they must be normalised so that both mantissae are expressed to the same power of 2. In doing so, if the smaller operand rolls down to 0 all of its significance is lost)

The value just stays the same, and you cannot reach the overflow/underflow.

http://www.fact-index.com/f/fl/floating_point_1.html

The minimum value to add to change the number is determined by the [machine epsilon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon)

The best way to toy with the limit is not to add but to multiply by `(1+FLT_EPSILON)` (amounts to add the number times `FLT_EPSILON`)

```
#include <float.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
 float f = FLT_MAX;

 f *= (1+FLT_EPSILON/2);
 printf("%f\n",f);

return 0;
}
```

this prints the number, unchanged. Absorption ignored the multiplication.

Now do that:

```
#include <float.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
 float f = FLT_MAX;

 f *= (1+FLT_EPSILON);
 printf("%f\n",f);

return 0;
}
```

and the output is

```
1.#INF00
```

In the case of `FLT_MAX`, on my machine, the limit number to add to trigger the overflow is way past 1: it is `40564816789451702000000000000000.000000` !

Comment: @user3691838 perhaps try adding a *large* value to the max (as just added to the answer).

Comment: I had not thought of this. If I loop a gazillion times on +=1 I will never change the value. I mean I knew that float was limited precision but thats still a surprise.

Comment: @user3691838 before adding the two operands, they must be normalised so that both mantissae are expressed to the same power of 2. In doing so, if the smaller operand rolls down to `0` all of its significance is lost. (That is not the same when operands are multiplied, when the mantissae are multiplied and the exponents are added).

Comment: @WeatherVane you need a laaaaaaarge value like > 40564816789451702000000000000000

Comment: @WeatherVane excellent explanation. I didn't go that far. Allow me to quote your comment in my answer.

Comment: Please do that.

Comment: I did (left out the mulitplication part for the sake of shortness :)). I'm surprised that there are no duplicates (searching for "absorption" yielded nothing so I answered)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, thank you!   This definitely helps me make sense of what is happening.

Comment: Note: that `1+FLT_EPSILON*0.5000001f` will also result in "infinity".

Answer (score 2):

## Floating point limits

There are macros that define the limits.
`FLT_MAX`, `FLT_MIN` are respectively the maximum and minimum values for the `float` type.

There are also other macros as well, such as `FLT_MAX_EXP` (maximum exponent defined in terms of `FLT_RADIX` which is generally valued at 2) and `FLT_MAX_10_EXP` (maximum exponent defined in base 10).

The smallest number representable in `float` is the floating point epsilon, defined in the `FLT_EPSILON` macro, valued at `1E-5`.

These macros can be found in `float.h`

## Precision

**Note**: In this explanation I will use a radix of 10 for the purposes of illustration. However C uses a radix defined by the `FLT_RADIX` macro mentioned above (usually valued at 2).

Floating point numbers are represented through a significand and an exponent:

`1234` = `1.234 x 10^3`

In C, single precision floating point numbers will give you 24 bits of significand, and 8 bits for the exponent. That means that if your significand has more digits than what can be encoded in the significant bits, it starts losing precision.

A very large number would be presented with a significand and an exponent.

`1000000000000001` would become `1.000000000000001 x 10^15`

This significand will be rounded as it is too large to be encoded in the significand bits. Likewise, adding small quantities to this number will also cause the significand to be rounded, therefore producing no increment.

Comment: Floating point numbers are usually encoded with an exponent power of 2, not 10.

Comment: @WeatherVane, IEEE754 uses a binary base, yes. I picked a decimal base example was just to illustrate the concept.